# Как сделать debug серверной функции JS в nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Доброго времени суток. Случилось так, что пришлось работать с незнакомым мне JS.
Есть код, который собирает ссылку типа строка для апи погоды (apixu.com). хотелось бы узнать, как можно устроить debug данной функции, без залива её на сервер каждый раз через nodeJS. При запуске функции через nodeJS функция выполняется и ничего не происходит.

Собственно, пример кода:

```
exports.RussianWeather = (req, res) => {
    // Get the city and date from the request
    let city = req.body.result.parameters['geo-city']; // city is a required parametr
    // Get the date for the weather forecast (if present)
    let date = '';
    if (req.body.result.parameters['date']) {
        date = req.body.result.parameters['date'];
    }
    // Call the weather API
    callWeatherApi(city, date).then((output) => {
        // Return the results of the weather API to API.AI
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ 'speech': output, 'displayText': output }));
}).catch((error) => {
        // If there is an error let the user know
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ 'speech': error, 'displayText': error }));
});
};
```

Функция:

```
exports.currentWeather = function currentWeather(query, callback, errcallback){
options.path = '/v1/current.json?key=' + apiKey + '&q=' + query + '&lang=ru';
http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  var data = '';
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    data += chunk;
  });
  res.on('end', function (chunk) {
    callback(data);
  });
}).on('error', function(err) {
    // handle errors with the request itself
    errcallback(err);
}).end();
}
```

Функция парса:

```
// parsing function
exports.datepars = function datepars(body){
console.log(body);
//let response = JSON.parse(body); error 'Unexpected end of JSON input'
let location = body['location'];
let forecast = body['forecast']['forecastday'][0];
let current = body['current']['condition'];
let currentConditions = current['condition'];
// Create response
let output = location;
console.log(output);
return output;
```

Я хочу понять, что возвращается мне в body в функции парса. 
console.log(body) - динамиться =\

Comment: JSON, возвращенный API

`{"location":{"name":"Москва","region":"Moscow City","country":"Россия","lat":55.75,"lon":37.62,"tz_id":"Europe/Moscow","localtime_epoch":1510727832,"localtime":"2017-11-15 9:37"}, ...}`

Comment: а ты функции сами вызываешь? В вопросе только примеры экспортов

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял что datepars(body) нужно выполнить в колбеке задаваемом в currentWeather. Примерно так:

```
var result;
currentWeather("blabla",(body)=>{result=datepars(body)},(error)=>{})
```

проверять лень

Answer (score 0):

В итоге, надо было закомментировать строки следующим образом и добавить вызов функции в конец. После чего console.log() заработал в Nodejs

```
    exports.RussianWeather = (req, res) => {
        // Get the city and date from the request
        let city = 'Moscow'; // city is a required parametr
        // Get the date for the weather forecast (if present)
        let date = '';
        /*if (req.body.result.parameters['date']) {
            date = req.body.result.parameters['date'];
        }*/
        // Call the weather API
        callWeatherApi(city, date).then((output) => {
            // Return the results of the weather API to API.AI
            //res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            //res.send(JSON.stringify({ 'speech': output, 'displayText': output }));
            console.log('API OK');
    }).catch((error) => {
            // If there is an error let the user know
            //res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            //res.send(JSON.stringify({ 'speech': error, 'displayText': error 
}));
            console.log('API ERR');
    });
    };
    exports.RussianWeather();
```